# stat_sum and stat_identity give weird results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code, including randomly generated demo data:

```
n <- 10
group <- rep(1:4, n)
mass.means <- c(10, 20, 15, 30)
mass.sigma <- 4
score.means <- c(5, 5, 7, 4)
score.sigma <- 3
mass <- as.vector(model.matrix(~0+factor(group)) %*% mass.means) +
  rnorm(n*4, 0, mass.sigma)
score <- as.vector(model.matrix(~0+factor(group)) %*% score.means) +
  rnorm(n*4, 0, score.sigma)
data <- data.frame(id = 1:(n*4), group, mass, score)
head(data)
```

Which gives:

```
  id group      mass    score
1  1     1 12.643603 5.015746
2  2     2 21.458750 5.590619
3  3     3 15.757938 8.777318
4  4     4 32.658551 6.365853
5  5     1  6.636169 5.885747
6  6     2 13.467437 6.390785
```

And then I want to plot the sum of "score", grouped by "group", in a bar chart:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = group, y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="sum") 
plot
```

This gives me: 
[image]

Weirdly, using `stat_identity` seems to give the result I am looking for:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = group, y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") 
plot
```

[image]

Is this a bug? Using ggplot2 1.0.0 on R

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2014                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        66913                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't find `stat="sum"` anywhere in the source code. Who told you it should work? Did you see it anywhere in the documentaitons?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Look for `stat_sum` in the documentation.

Comment: @Roland, yes but have you ever seen `stat="sum"` in docs? especially combined with `geom_bar`?

Comment: You can pass all `stat_*` functions to geoms like this. It may not make sense or result in errors, but it is possible.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818188/ggplot-geom-bar-with-stat-sum/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = group, y = score)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "sum", geom = "bar", position = "identity")
plot
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
aggregate(score ~ group, data=data, FUN=sum)
#  group    score
#1     1 51.71279
#2     2 58.94611
#3     3 67.52100
#4     4 39.24484
```

**Edit:**

`stat_sum` does not work, because it doesn't just return the sum. It returns the "number of observations at position" and "percent of points in that panel at that position". It was designed for a different purpose. The docs say " Useful for overplotting on scatterplots."

`stat_identity` (kind of) works because `geom_bar` by default stacks the bars. You have many bars on top of each other in contrast to my solution that gives you just one bar per group. Look at this:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = group, y = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "red") 
plot
```

Also consider the warning:

```
Warning message:
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0
```

Comment: Fine, this works, but it still doesn't answer my question. Why does `stat="sum"` not work and why does `stat="identity"` produce what I would expect from `stat="sum"`? The grammar of graphics seems to be well conceptualized, but ggplot2 is sometimes such a PITA... :-(

Comment: is it possible to plot the labels of the sum after using stat summary? I mean plotting the totals?