# ggplot geom_bar with stat = "sum"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a bar chart summing a variable along two dimensions, one will be spread along `x`, and the other will be spread vertically (stacked).

I would expect the two following instructions to do the same, but they don't and only the 2nd one gives the desired output (where I aggregate the data myself).

I'd like to understand what's going on in the first case, and if there's a way to use `ggplot2` 's built-in aggregation features to get the right output.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
p1 <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,price,fill=color)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="sum",na.rm=TRUE)
```

yielding this plot:

[image]

```
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds %>%
                group_by(cut,color) %>%
                summarize_at("price",sum,na.rm=T),
              aes(cut,price,fill=color)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",na.rm=TRUE)
```

yielding this picture:

[image]

Here's where the top of our bars should be, p1 doesn't give these values:

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarize_at("price",sum,na.rm=TRUE)
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# cut    price
# <ord>    <int>
# 1      Fair  7017600
# 2      Good 19275009
# 3 Very Good 48107623
# 4   Premium 63221498
# 5     Ideal 74513487
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding the `stat` option for `geom_bar`. In this case, since you want the values for each factor to be summed up within each bar, and the bars to be colored based off how much of that total sum is in each color, you can simplify the call to `geom_col` which uses the values as heights for the bar; and therefore "sums" all the values within each category. For example, the following will give the desired output:

```
p1 <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,price,fill=color)) + 
        geom_col(na.rm=TRUE)
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `geom_bar` with a stat call, then you want to use the "identity" stat:

```
p1 <- ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,price,fill=color)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", na.rm=TRUE)
```

For more information, consider this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965637/6722506

Comment: Alternatively, I think `ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,fill=color,weight = price)) + 
 geom_bar(na.rm=TRUE)` will also yield the same result as `p2`.

Comment: ^Trips an error. To use `geom_bar`, you have to specify `stat` as `"identity"`.

Comment: It does not trip an error for me, have you run it? You may have not noticed that I'm using the `weight` aesthetic, not the `y` aesthetic. That makes a difference.

Comment: Whoops! didn't notice that part. Yours as is will also work.

Comment: I see, I was using the wrong stat basically. That answers the second question. It's confusing to me as this data is obviously summed ("identity" cannot be shown on a bar plot by definition as I see it). Do you know what statsum did in my case ?

Comment: @joran that's a cool trick as well, I would suppose that it's a bit slower though (multiplying then summing), for cases where it matters.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper found this answer to your question! https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965637/6722506 ... it appears `stat = "sum"` isn't recognized for `geom_bar` directly. Also gives more insight on the solutions I posted above.

Comment: great find! it also solves my confusion above, with `stat_identity` you technically have a bunch of bars stacked on top of each other, but as they have the same color, it appears just like a sum. The link also have a cool use of `stat_summary` that I didn't know

Comment: That link, even though it answers the question quite directly, was surprisingly hard to find! haha But glad to help :)